# Cant install ipa adhoc although added UDID

Tags: ios, ipa

I have a trouble which i never meet before. And dont know how to fix. Really need your help
I have a ipa (use Adhoc provision). My device cant install but device of my partner can install easy. Although 2 device were added UDID.

I was creat new certificate and new provision, still fail
Lets help me if you know. thanks so much !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvPXq.png)

Comment: by the way it should show some error message, did you get any message from itune?

Comment: mostly reason of installing problem come from Bundle identifiers already have in app in the phone

Comment: Yes, i think so, but i checked all my apps. and i make sure, have no application have a same bundleID

Comment: or iOS version of the iPhone lower than supported version of the app

Comment: Try to go to settings->general->device management. Every profiles should be trusted.